# appmaker how to change the name in the browser history

Tags: url, browser-history, google-app-maker

I would like instead of having the name of the app, in the browser history, the name of the customer, so It would be easier to go back to a specific customer...

I use

```
 google.script.history.push(
          {'timestamp': new Date().getTime()},
          {'Patient': Patient},
          "test"
      );
```

To push parameters to the url, and though maybe the last parameter would appear in the browser history, but that is not the case, only the app name is shown... 
Any Idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately App Maker applications exist as frames, with a different origin (url hostname) than the parent window.

This means that any attempt to change the window title (which is used as the title in the browser history) results in an error.